# deploy docker image to desktop users via installer

Tags: docker

I have a Docker image with a web application and its dependencies (Java, etc.).  I'd like to package this up into Windows/Mac installers that will allow end-users to run the container.  I do not want them to have to download Docker first, and then go to the command line to download and run an image, as they are not technical users.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write code to install and execute docker.